# A good way to share custom snippets for Emmet in SublimeText 3

Tags: zurb-foundation, sublimetext3, emmet

I created a library of snippets for Foundation 6 in Emmet for SublimeText 3 with options, etc. It would be nice to be able to easily share them somehow, but I am not sure of the best way to do this.

I don't think a package would work since Emmet is a package inside of ST3 already. I didn't see any docs on being able to extend emmet with alibrary loader or anything like that.

Is it just a manual process of copy/paste in the Emmet.sublime-settings file that's available?

Answer (score 0):

Just [create a package](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package) on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io). There are currently 346 packages with the [snippets](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/snippets) label, so this would not be the first time someone has done something like this. There are plenty of packages that extend other packages, such as the [`SublimeLinter`](https://packagecontrol.io/search/sublimelinter) ecosystem. There are already other [snippets extensions](https://packagecontrol.io/search/emmet) for Emmet, too. I would suggest opening an [issue](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues) to let the author of Emmet what you're doing, and he may even put a note in the Emmet README if you ask nicely.